# After rolling 6 dice, what is the percentage of getting at least two 6?

Tags: probability

> After rolling 6 dice, what is the percentage of getting at least two 6?

Of course all dice a six-sided.

I have asked a friend he didn't fully elaborate on the calculation, but he suggested to use the method of the Bernoulli distribution.

I am from a programmer background, I have no idea of how to implement this in a computer program at the moment other than picking a math probability book and start reading from page 1.

Sorry but I really can't figure out how to setup a math model to work this out.

Comment: For a Bernoulli distribution, where success has probability $p$ ($p=\frac 16$ in this case), the probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials is $\binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

Comment: You can look for Binomial distribution. The result of each roll can be modeled by a Bernoulli random variable - equals to $1$ if the result is $6$ and $0$ otherwise. The total number of $6$ is the sum of these identical and independent Bernoulli trials which follows a Binomial distribution. For the calculation please follow the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Instead of calculating $P(A)=$the probability of at least two sixes, calculate $P(\neg A) = $the probability of fewer than $2$ sixes. Then, use the fact that $P(\neg A) + P(A) = 1$.

Also, to calculate the probability of a particular number of sixes, take a look at the Bernoulli distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a binomial distribution where $n=6, p=\frac16$

$P[n,k]=\binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

So the probability of getting at least two 6s in 6 rolls=1-P[6,0]-P[6,1]=$\frac{12281}{46656}$ Hence, the percentage of getting two 6s is 26.322%